# Decode Vim find/replace string that calls a function

Tags: vim

I am using the following Vim command line that inserts line numbers to the beginning of lines:

`:let i = 1 | %s/^/\='LINE_' . Inc()/g`

`Inc()` is a function that increments the `i` variable.

This is all working fine.  My questions:

1) What does the dot do in the replacement part?:

```
:let i = 1 | %s/^/\='LINE_' . Inc()/g
                            ^
```

2) What does the pipe character do?  Is there actual piping going on, or is it just syntax?

3) What does the `\=` do?  I think it is used to call the function, but Vim help only shows information for `\=` as being a quantifier in regex.

4) I have not been able to insert a space **after** the line number and the first character of the actual line.  How can I do this?  Anything I place after `Inc()` in the replacement part is either being ignored or causing an *E15 invalid expression* error.

I am using Vim 7.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: Best way to find help on a Vim topic is `CTRL-D`. For example type `:h \=<C-D>` to see all the help tags that contain `\=`. In this case `:s\=` is the right one and you can find lots more information there.

Comment: @glts: +1 THANK YOU! This is an invaluable piece of advice. I was just thinking that the entire time I was grappling with the problem of finding out information about the `\=` expression, it was present within the application's help file, but I did not know how to access it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some explanation:

1. `.` expression will concatenate two strings. See `:h expr-.`
2. `|` will separate to ex-commands. See `:h :bar`
3. A replacement starting with `\=` in `:s` command means the rest of the replacement is to be treated as an vim expression. See `:h :s\=`
4. Concatenate a string with a space after the `Inc()` function call. `:let i = 1 | %s/^/\='LINE_' . Inc() . ' '/g`

Comment: I think I was the one who pushed you over 10K! Congratulations.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you. Cheers!